# JPA EntityGraph based on meta model containing MappedSuperclass not possible?

Tags: java, jpa, entitygraph

I'm trying to use the type safe method `EntityGraph.addAttributeNodes(Attribute<T, ?> ... attribute)` for constructing my entity graph. I have a type hierarchy with a `@MappedSuperclass` that basically looks like this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    @Id
    private int dbid;
}

@Entity
public class Entity extends BaseEntity
{
    private String someAttribute;
}
```

EclipseLink creates this meta model:

```
@Generated(value="EclipseLink-2.5.2.v20140319-rNA", date="2015-08-07T10:46:31")
@StaticMetamodel(BaseEntity.class)
public abstract class BaseEntity_ { 
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<BaseEntity, Integer> dbid;
}

@Generated(value="EclipseLink-2.5.2.v20140319-rNA", date="2015-08-07T10:46:31")
@StaticMetamodel(Entity.class)
public class Entity_ extends BaseEntity_ {
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Entity, String> someAttribute;
}
```

The problem is that I cannot refer to the `dbid` attribute with the entity graph API:

```
EntityGraph<Entity> graph = em.createEntityGraph( Entity.class );
graph.addAttributeNodes( Entity_.dbid ); // does not compile: "The method addAttributeNodes(String...) in the type EntityGraph<Entity> is not applicable for the arguments (SingularAttribute<BaseEntity,Integer>)"
```

For this to work, wouldn't the method signature need to look like this: `EntityGraph.addAttributeNodes(Attribute<? super T, ?> ... attribute)`? Is this a shortcoming of the specification or am I overlooking something?

It seems to me that this is a problem related to the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13048743/jpa-static-metamodel-with-mappedsuperclass-with-a-bit-of-generation-gap-patter). As the author of that question points out, the Criteria API `get` method for singular attributes does indeed use `? super X` to define the type parameter.

But even when I add the `someAttribute` node, there's still this somewhat ugly warning, which I presume can only be suppressed at best:

```
graph.addAttributeNodes( Entity_.someAttribute ); // generates warning: "Type safety: A generic array of Attribute<Entity,?> is created for a varargs parameter"
```

Comment: i guess i have a similar problem: there is Path.get(SingularAttribute<? super X, Y> attribute) but Path.get(PluralAttribute<X, C, E> collection); -just to be used in Predicates. How you worked around this issue?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't remember exactly, but I believe I gave up on the type-safe construction of entity graphs in this case and resorted to the non-safe way with @NamedEntityGraph on the entities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd agree.

Clearly if you changed your code to

```
EntityGraph<BaseEntity> graph = em.createEntityGraph(BaseEntity.class);
graph.addAttributeNodes(BaseEntity_.dbid );
```

then it would compile. 
The problem does indeed seem to be in the spec/API where it has EntityGraph's generic type being applied to the addAttributeNodes argument (hence not allowing superclass fields). Yes, it does say that "T" is the type of the *root* entity, but that can't mean that they expect people to always use the MappedSuperclass?

I'd also confirm that by using "`? super T`" for the Attribute generic type fixes it (taking a javax.persistence jar source and modifying/rerunning).

I raised it as an [issue on JPA](https://java.net/jira/browse/JPA_SPEC-112), not that I'd recommend holding breath for an update

Comment: Thanks for bringing this forward to the spec guys.